# How to remove validation error message upon input field change?

Tags: checkout, validation, form-validation

I have installed a module that adds another payment method, which has additional input options, and I want to make those options mandatory.

I've added a validator to validate `#co-payment-form`'s input fields, as described in Magento's docs – [Add custom validations before order placement](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html).

I have added these attributes to the `<select>` element: `data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-select':true}"` and `class="select validate-select"`.

And the validator looks like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/validation'
], function ($)
{
    'use strict';
    return {
        paymentFormSelector: '#co-payment-form',
        validate: function ()
        {
            const jqPaymentForm = $(this.paymentFormSelector).validation();
            return $(jqPaymentForm).valid();
        }
    };
});
```

Now, when I do not select anything and click on "Place Order"/"Submit Order", this validator gets called all right and the field gets a red error message.

How do I remove the message once the user has selected something?

I see that, for example, the mandatory fields of the shipping address form get all red upon trying to place an order, but once I start writing in such a field, the error message disappears at once.

How can I get the same for this custom validator?